Will Labour party MPs sit on both sides of the House of Commons?
A characteristic feature of UK parliament is that the House of Commons is split in two sides, one for Conservatives and one for Labour, with minor parties filling some of the remaining seats (current floorplan here).
Yesterday's election gave Labour more than double MPs than Conservatives. Will this unprecedented result mean that Labour MPs will be sitting on both sides of the chamber? Or can the sides not be crossed, by definition?
(In any case, there are not enough seats for all MPs, with many having to stand when important sessions are held)

There are no 'Conservative' and 'Labour' sides in the House of Commons, only government and opposition. Looking towards the Speaker’s Chair, the government sit on the left and the opposition parties on the right.

The link in the question shows the floor plan of the House of Commons of Canada, not of the United Kingdom.
